# Date interpretation problem

Tags: date-and-time

What am I doing wrong?

```
DateObject[{"1/31/2020 2:00 AM", {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year", " ", "Hour12", ":", "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}}]
```

> DateObject::str: String 1/31/2020 2:00 AM cannot be interpreted as a
>   date.

The line without AM/PM works fine

```
DateObject[{"1/31/2020 2:00", {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year", " ", "Hour12", ":", "Minute"}}]
```

Comment: Looks like a version/OS-related issue. It works without an error message in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10 -64 bit).

Comment: Also works in version 12.0 (Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)).